# Some basic problems on the construction of python3 base classes？

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner. I've defined the following classes. They look the same. I'm a little dizzy. I don't know what the difference is?

1. My purpose is to define a base class. Why use `object`? I think `B` is what I want.
2. Do I have to use the `super ()` function to return? What do `CLS, * args, * kwargs` stand for?

python code :

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("A.__new__called")
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    
class B:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("B.__new__called")
        return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class C():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("C.__new__called")
        return super(C, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    
class D():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("D.__new__called")
        return super(D, cls).__new__(cls)

class E():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("E.__new__called")
        return super(E, cls).__new__(cls)

class F():
    print("F.__new__called")

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
d = D()
e = E()
f = F()
```

result :

```
F.__new__called
A.__new__called
B.__new__called
C.__new__called
D.__new__called
E.__new__called
```

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects out, it should be pretty enlightening

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Few comments:

1. object is inherited by default in python3.x onwards and thus no need for this explicit inheritance as required in python2.x
2. super() also doesn't need any arguments in py3.x.

   ```
   class A:
        def __init__(self):
           print("Here in init")

        def __new__(cls,*args,**kargs):
           print("Here in new")
           super().__new__(cls,**kargs)
   ```

**new** is always class method and called before an object is instantiated. For example, if you create the object above, following print statement will be in that order: first what is in **new** and then **init**. So **new** is used if you want to do something before an object is instantiated. super() calls the inherited base class (default object in this case) to create the object.  *args and **kargs are just list of arguments and key arguments to pass when you create the object.

**obj = A()**

It will print following:

```
Here in new
Here in init
```

Comment: super() calls the inherited base class (default object in this case) to create the object？what do you mean? Class A: so  A is base class， It also needs to inherit the object?

Comment: It means whether you explicitly write or not, in python3x, if base class isn't mentioned, it will automatically have object as base class. You can check by printing  __bases__. Example: **class A: pass** is our class. **print(A.__bases__)** will show object as base class automatically

Comment: So the base class I defined in the code is not a real base class. It still inherits the real base class object (here)?